# AngularJS - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'error in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, ecmascript-6

I don't get any errors on Chrome and website is working. But, in safari most of the pages doesn't load at all. This is the error i get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'
```

Code behind this :-

> if($scope.listOfAccounts.some(ele=>ele.name===$scope.newAccount.name))

I  use the angular.js "angular": "~1.3.12",

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Nor Safari 9.1 (and previous) neither IE 11 (and previous) browser does not support an arrow expressions.
Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Right, any solution for this issue

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this

Answer (score 2):

You are using the ES6 arrow function which are [not supported in Safari and Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions). Generally, ES6 support is still somewhat limited and should not be used as is. Instead, you should transpile it to ES5. Well-known transpilers are for example [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler).