# (Firebase Storage) hosted image doesnt display on iPhone browser

Tags: iphone, firebase, firebase-storage

Trying to display an image and link from Firebase Storage & Database. Works perfectly fine on desktop browsers and also android devices, but does not display on iOS devices (mobile safari). Is there anything obvious that I am missing here or could it be a bug? The page presents correctly with just a space where the image link should be.

Code lifted out below. Obviously as works on other browsers Firebase all initialized correctly so not included the script tags.

```
<div class="livewire1">

<a href="" target="_blank" ><img id="myimg" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>


<script>

  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function (element, index) {
      var dbRef1 = firebase.database().ref().child('sponsorlink/hole01');
      dbRef1.on('value', snap => element.href = snap.val());

  });

  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  var imagesRef = storageRef.child('banner_ads');
  var fileName = 'ban_01.png';
  var bannerRef = imagesRef.child(fileName);

  bannerRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
      var banner1 = url;
      document.getElementById('myimg').src = banner1;

  }).catch(function(error) {

  });
</script>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger? Does it go into the `then()` block? What is the `url` at that point?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen,  Hi, dbRef1.on('value', snap => element.href = snap.val());   in the debugger in safari this gives an error for an unexpected token  ">"   also this is an image of a url printed in the console, not sure if this is what you mean however [Image](http://www.w1gcms.club/debug/screen1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem indirectly thanks to Frank van Puffelen and checking the debugger on safari mobile, but the unexpected syntax ">" on the snap value
 `dbRef1.on('value', snap => element.href = snap.val());` 
seemed to be what was causing the storage image not to load.

ES6 arrow function which are not supported in Safari and Internet Explorer. [AngularJS - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'error in Safari Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277303/angularjs-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-error-in-safari-browser)

resolved with following:

```
dbRef1.on('value', function(snap) { element.href = snap.val()});
```